# Open panel half the size of window from center of window to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like that when I click on a button, a panel half the size of the window opens **from the center of the window** and expands to the right. I also don't want the panel to push the current contents of the window out, just overlay over it.

Every example of this I've tried to find opens panels from the right to the center and pushes the contents of the window too.

Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the css that should do the trick.
Notice the position value:

```
.panel{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  left:50%;
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
}
```

You may also have to put some z-index value to the css, in case your main content will be overlaying the panel for some reason.